# Compile-time assert for string equality

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Is this possible to do using templates?

There are two string constants. They come from defines in different modules. They must be equal, or I shall raise compile-time error if they are not equal. Can I do this using templates?

```
#define MY_STRING "foo"
CompileAssertIfStringsNotEqual(MY_STRING, HIS_STRING);
```

P.S. I was deluded by assuming that "abc"[0] is constant expression. It is not.  Weird omission in the language. It would be possibe had "abc"[0] been constand expression.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is only possible with C++0x. No chance with C++03.

EDIT: Constexpr function for C++0x. The following works with GCC4.6, however the Standard is not explicit in allowing it, and a small wording tweak was and is being considered to make the spec allow it.

```
constexpr bool isequal(char const *one, char const *two) {
  *one == *two && (!*one || isEqual(one + 1, two + 1));
}

static_assert(isequal("foo", "foo"), "this should never fail");
static_assert(!isequal("foo", "bar"), "this should never fail");
```

The compiler is required to track the reference to characters of the string literals already, throughout all the recursions. Just the final read from characters isn't explicitly allowed (if you squint, you can read it as being allowed, IMO). If your compiler doesn't want to accept the above simple version, you can make your macro declare arrays and then compare those

```
#define CONCAT1(A, B) A ## B
#define CONCAT(A, B) CONCAT1(A, B)

#define CHECK_EQUAL(A, B) \
  constexpr char CONCAT(x1, __LINE__)[] = A, \
                 CONCAT(x2, __LINE__)[] = B; \
  static_assert(isequal(CONCAT(x1, __LINE__), CONCAT(x2, __LINE__)), \
     "'" A "' and '"  B "' are not equal!")
```

That's definitely fine.

```
CHECK_EQUAL("foo", "foo"); /* will pass */
CHECK_EQUAL("foo", "bar"); /* will fail */
```

Note that `CHECK_EQUAL` can be used inside of functions. The FCD did make a change to allow `constexpr` functions to read from automatic arrays in their invocation substitution. See [DR1197](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1197).

Comment: +1 but, I've always suspected this might be possible in C++ using metaprogramming.  But I've never been able to accomplish it.  With C++0x on the horizon, I gave up trying.

Comment: This means it might be possible to write a compiler in the C++ template language. Woohoo!

Comment: i already see some boost guy come up with a templated "DSL" that gets translated to a sequence of constexpr function calls :) Just a matter of time for them.

Comment: I think that passing two additional arguments to isequal() -- sizeof(string1) and sizeof(string2), makes isequal less dependent on incompatibility you hint at.

Comment: Max string length is depends on max recursion stack size defined for concrete compiler. *not sure but as far as I know usually 256*

Answer (score -3):

No.  You can not.  Not even with `boost::mpl` or the `boost` preprocessor library.  Even if you were to stipulate that the compiler could coalesce all duplicate string references into the same pointer value at compile-time, the pointer value does not exist until link-time.  What you want to implement happens at preprocessor time, and then is asserted at compile-time.

Comment: And yet, templates do not accept "quoted strings" for specialization.

Comment: Nor do they accept `double` or `float` or any other non-integer value for specialization of a `template something<int N>`.

Comment: Yet compile-time template calculations on doubles are possible -> http://tinyurl.com/6k9ry65