# Checking that macro parameter is one of the allowed ones?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'd like to accomplish something like the following:

```
#define FOO(bar, ...) \
  static_assert(bar == "foo" || bar == "bazz", "Invalid value for bar") \
  ...
```

In other words, I'd like to check at compile time that the value given to the macro is one of the allowed ones. What is the cleanest way for doing a compile time string comparison when comparing against strings of variable length?

Comment: I would say the cleanest way is "don't use a macro"... With C++17 you have a lot of compile-time facilities at your disposal.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Do you have a template sketch?

Comment: Also, since you ask "what's the cleanest way": Do you have a dirty one?

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-strings-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives) and the answers. I think it's a dup. (I found that by googling -- hint, hint.)

Comment: this is almost the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490858/how-can-you-compare-two-character-strings-statically-at-compile-time

Comment: This is basically used for some logging stuff where I need the source line number and file of the caller. To my knowledge this isn't doable without using macros.

Comment: For the dirty one... I can compare each character one at a time, e.g. something like (#bar)[0] == "f" || ... || (sizeof(#bar) > 4 && (#bar)[3] == "z") || sizeof(#bar) < 6))

Comment: Why don't use `enum` instead of string?

Comment: For not using an enum: I don't want to pollute the namespace and using an enum class would require more typing by the macro user.

Comment: I don't think "more typing" is sufficient reason not to use an enum. The benefits outweigh the drawbacks in my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use string views.

```
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

// Note the sv after the string
#define FOO(bar, ...) \
  static_assert(bar == "foo"sv || bar == "bazz"sv, "Invalid value for bar") \
  ...
```

The expression `"foo"sv` invokes a literal operator. It constructs a `std::string_view` from `"foo"`. `std::string_view` has overloaded `==` operators for comparing with strings. These overloaded operators are `constexpr` which means that they can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Didn't know about the "sv" trick! This was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.