# Eclipse and C based issue: #defines aren't working outside of header files

Tags: c, eclipse, ide, c-preprocessor

Using Eclipse IDE. Problem is that `#defines` aren't passing from the headers to the c and h files. Not sure if it's a project settings thing or what, but Visual Studio IDE is not giving me any trouble on the same project. Some of the projects in Eclipse don't have this problem though. Any ideas on what may be wrong? See example of the problem below.

Even though EXAMPLE is defined in `header1.h`, it is not recognized as defined in `main.c`. There is no issue with the compiler finding the headers either. Thanks for the help all.

Header1.h

```
#define EXAMPLE 1
```

main.c

```
#include "Header1.h"

#if defined(EXAMPLE)

/* code here */

#endif
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty basic feature that could go wrong; can you pare down your problem into something that someone else could easily test?

Answer (score 0):

You mention there is no issue with the compiler and visual studio, so assuming you are referring to the code being grayed out in the Eclipse IDE?  If so, check the Indexer settings

> Preferences --> C/C++ --> Indexer
>
> Check Enable Indexer Check Index Source files not included in the
>   build Check Automatically update the index Check Use Active build
>   Configuration

etc,...

hope this was relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
#ifdef EXAMPLE
```

instead of

```
#if defined(EXAMPLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Behavior similar to that in the question can be seen when using `#define`s that are strings, not integers.

The following code seems like it should run `Code();` only when `MODE` is equal to the string `different`:

**mode.h**

```
#define MODE something
```

**different.cpp**

```
#include "mode.h"

#if MODE == different
  Code();
#endif
```

Eclipse shows `Code();` as being active when it appears it should be inactive.  The reason for this is that the preprocessor does not support string comparisons, only integer ones<sup>1</sup>.

When mousing over `MODE` in `different.cpp`, `MODE` is shown as having the value `something`.  Although this is technically correct, it can be misleading since both `MODE` and `something` evaluate to the same thing (a defined but empty value).  Given that they both have the same value (nothing) they evaluate as being equal and `Code();` is run.

<sup>1</sup> This is gone into in more detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-strings-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives).

---

**Solutions**

Two possible ways of correctly handling this come to mind:

- Assign numeric values to each option
- Use unique `#define`s for each option

**Use numeric values**

The code could be written as follows:

**mode.h**

```
#define MODE_something 0
#define MODE_different 1

#define MODE MODE_something
```

**different.cpp**

```
#include "mode.h"

#if MODE == MODE_different
  Code();
#endif
```

In this case the code works as expected since `MODE` and `MODE_different` evaluate to two distinct values (`0` and `1`, respectively).

**Use unique `#define`s**

Another approach is to use uniquely-named macros for each option.  For example:

**mode.h**

```
// Select the active mode:

#define MODE_something
//#define MODE_different
```

**different.cpp**

```
#include "mode.h"

#ifdef MODE_different

Code();

#endif
```