# About ## preprocessor in C

Tags: c-preprocessor

Given

```
#define cat(x,y) x##y
```

The call `cat(a,1)` returns `a1`, but `cat(cat(1,2),3)` is undefined. 
However if I also define `#define xcat(x,y) cat(x,y)`, then the result of `xcat(xcat(1,2),3)` is  now `123`. Can anybody please explain in detail why this is so?

Comment: Do you mean `then the result of xcat(xcat(1,2),3) is now 123`?

Comment: @notfed:Sorry I made a mistake in writing the question .Yes the result of xcat(xcat(1,2),3) is 123

Answer (score 2):

I tested this using both GCC and Clang.

GCC gives the error:

```
test.c:6:1: error: pasting ")" and "3" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Clang gives the error:

```
test.c:6:11: error: pasting formed ')3', an invalid preprocessing token
  int b = cat(cat(1,2),3);
```

What appears to be happening is that the compiler wraps the result of `cat(1,2)` in parentheses as soon as it is expanded; so when you call `cat(1,2)` in your code, it really gives you `(12)`.  Then, calling `cat((12),3)` again leads to `((12)3)`, which is not a valid token, and this results in a compile error.

The common opinion is "when using the token-pasting operator (##), you should use two levels of indirection" (i.e., use your `xcat` workaround).  See [Why do I need double layer of indirection for macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231966/why-do-i-need-double-layer-of-indirection-for-macros) and [What should be done with macros that need to paste two tokens together?](https://web.archive.org/web/20120229073241/http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html).

Comment: In my question after substituting xcat(x,y) with cat(x,y) it again becomes cat(cat(1,2),3) then even now it should return invalid token. I am unable to understand how the two levels of indirection is working. I read the above URL but still it is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

In xcat(x,y), the x and y are not adjacent to the ## operator, and 
so they undergo macro expansion before being substituted.

So x is identified as xcat(1,2) and y is identified as 3. But prior 
to substitution, x is macro-expanded to cat(1,2), which turns into 1##2 
which turns into 12. So ultimately, xcat(xcat(1,2),3) will expand 
to cat(12,3), which will turn out 123.

**This Works --> cat(xcat(1,2),3) --> cat(cat(1,2),3) --> cat(12,3)**

The behavior is well-defined because all of the token pastings 
result in valid preprocessor tokens i.e any expanded xpression should be a valid token at any stage.

Comment: Well, your example didn't work, but `xcat(cat(1,2),3)` did anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if cat is actually gonna be expanded for 2 consecutive times. That's why I wonder why would compiler even produce such a message like `'pasting ")" and "3" does not give a valid preprocessing token'`.
Also, I don't think the inner cat is gonna be expanded first. So, I presume the output would be `cat(1,2)3`. That direct me to cogitate how would the compiler interpret this.