# Behavior of ## operator in nested call

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was reading a book on C programming language where I found:

```
#define cat(x,y) x##y
#define xcat(x,y) cat(x,y)
```

calling `cat(cat(1,2),3)` produces error whereas calling `xcat(xcat(1,2),3)` produces expected result `123`.

How are both working differently ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do i need double layer of indirection for macros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231966/why-do-i-need-double-layer-of-indirection-for-macros)

Answer (score 5):

Macros whose replacement lists depends on `##` usually can't be called in nested fashion.
`cat(cat(1,2),3)` is not expanded in a normal fashion, with `cat(1,2)` yielding `12` and then `cat(12, 3)` yielding `123`.
**Macro parameters that are preceded or followed by `##` in a replacement list aren't expanded at the time of substitution.**

**6.10.3.1 Argument substitution**

> 1 After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified,
>   argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, **unless preceded
>   by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token** (see below), is replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
>   expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are
>   completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other
>   preprocessing tokens are available.

As a result, `cat(cat(1,2),3)` expands to `cat(1,2)3`, which can't be expanded further, because there is no macro named `cat(1,2)3`.

In case

```
#define xcat(x,y) cat(x,y)
```

writing `xcat(xcat(1,2),3)` will work. As the preprocessor expands the outer call of `xcat`, it will expand `xcat(1,2)` as well; the difference is that **`xcat`'s replacement list does not contain `##`** anymore.

```
xcat(xcat(1,2),3) ==> cat(12, 3) ==> 12##3 ==> 123
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it were more explicit about how xcat works. But the question is a duplicate and there are excellent answers to the original.

Comment: @rici; I read the answers in the provided link, but none of them answered about the working both o `#define`.

Comment: I had always wondered why you needed such convoluted macros to do things like make the version string in APR... this makes sense... I hadn't ever bothered to learn why, just copied the form of something that already worked (engineers do that right ;)

Comment: Should the word "deference" be "difference"? SO won't let me make that change because the edit is less than 6 characters...

Comment: @haccks: You have to read 6.10.3.1 in conjunction with 6.10.3.3. `cat(cat(1,2),3)` is first replaced with `cat(1,2) ## 3` (the parameters are replaced literally, rather than with macro expansion). Then `##` attempts to concatenate `)` with `3`. However, `)3` is not a valid preprocessing token, so that's UB by 6.10.3.3/3 (8th line). I reread the linked question and also the question unearthed by Jayesh, and I think Chris Dodd's answer comes closest, but your answer is getting there :)

Comment: @rici; Thanks for the quote and letting me know about the behavior :)