# How to compare $PRODUCT_NAME in a prefix header?

Tags: ios, c-preprocessor

I am working on a project with multiple targets,
I have a preprocessor macro in build settings:

```
PRODUCT_NAME=\@\"$PRODUCT_NAME\"
```

now in AppName-Prefix.pch I have defined the $PRODUCT_NAME as:

```
#define ACTIVE_PRODUCT PRODUCT_NAME
```

how can I check if ACTIVE_PRODUCT is equal to a string?

I want to do something like this e.g.

```
if ACTIVE_PRODUCT == @"Product 1"
#define MY_VAR @"Test 1
#endif

if ACTIVE_PRODUCT == @"Product 2"
#define MY_VAR @"Test 2
```

So I can use MY_VAR in my code depending on the $PRODUCT_NAME

Please assist!
regards,
Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there’s a [previous question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888), and the answer seems to be that it’s not possible (see the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/cpp/ifstrcmp.html)). What I try to do is avoid the preprocessor as soon as possible, moving all processing to Objective-C. So instead of `#defining` your variables, you may set a regular Objective-C variable and continue processing in Objective-C:

```
static NSString *const ProductName = /* create string from PRODUCT_NAME */;
```

And later:

```
NSString *const MyVar = [ProductName isEqualToString:…] ? @"Foo" : @"Bar";
```

Of course this assumes that you only need `MyVar` in source code, not in resources like plists.

Comment: Thanks, yep seems not possible. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok since comparing strings seems not possible I used the following walkaround:

in each target I defined PRODUCT1=\@\"$PRODUCT_NAME\" .... PRODUCT2=\@\"$PRODUCT_NAME\" etc.

then in app-name-prefix.pch I did the following:

```
#if defined (PRODUCT1)
#define MY_VAR @"Test 1"
....
#endif

#if defined (PRODUCT2)
#define MY_VAR @"Test 2"
...
#endif
```

This solved the problem in my case.
Any other ways will be appreciated also.