# Why doesn't #if preprocessor work?

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

With the following code, I always get "VGA" as output ,when I intend to get "NOT VGA"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define ADAPTER NVGA
#if ADAPTER==VGA
 int main()
 {
 printf("VGA");
 getch();
 return 0;
 }
#else
     int main()
 {
 printf(" NOT VGA");
 getch();
 return 0;
 }
 #endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to compare string in C conditional preprocessor-directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-string-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives)

Comment: @Mauren OP is not trying to compare *strings* in `#if`, but (most probably) identifiers not `#define`d to any value (so they evaluate to zero in `#if`).

Comment: @Zack ah I see. I haven't realized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question is, where are `VGA` and `NVGA` defined?

If they are not defined, they will equal `0` according to C standard (N1570 - 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion - paragraph 4):

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary
>   operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically
>   identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing
>   token is converted into a token.

Which means your comparison will be `#if 0==0`, which is identical to `#if 1`.

To fix this, you need to define both `VGA` and `NVGA` to have different values:

```
#define VGA  1
#define NVGA 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities, and I can't tell which.  The most likely is that, because neither `NVGA` nor `VGA` is a `#define`d macro, they are both evaluated as zero in `#if` and therefore considered to be equal. (This is a rule of the language.)  The second possibility is that your system's `stdio.h` or `conio.h` defines `NVGA` to `VGA`.

To find out which, compile this program and see what happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
/* these numbers are chosen at random */
#define NVGA 8446
#define VGA 13060
#define ADAPTER NVGA
int main(void)
{
#if ADAPTER == VGA
    puts("VGA");
#else
    puts("NOT VGA");
#endif
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

If it produces the output you expected (i.e. "NOT VGA"), your problem is the first one.  If you get an error about redefining `NVGA` or `VGA`, your problem is the second one.

Comment: Thanks.It's the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Because NVGA itself hasn't been defined. Instead try this:

```
#define NVGA 0
#define VGA 1

#define ADAPTER VGA

#if ADAPTER==VGA
  /* insert VGA code here*/
#else
  /* insert NVGA code here*/
#endif
```