# Way to compare strings in C preprocessor? (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Is there a better way to do this (in GCC C)?

I'm trying to define some symbols representing the hardware platform, to be used for conditional compilation.

But I also want printable strings describing the hardware (for diagnostics).

Ideally I'd like be able to do:

```
#define HARDWARE "REV4C"

#if (HARDWARE == "REV4C")
    #define LED_RED      // define pin addresses, blah blah...
#endif

printf("HARDWARE %s\n", HARDWARE);
```

But I don't think that's allowed in C. This works, but it's ugly:

```
#define REV4C   (403)    // symbols for conditional compilation
#define REV421  (421) 

//#define HARDWARE REV4C // choose hardware platform (just one)
#define HARDWARE REV421

#if (HARDWARE == REV421) // define strings for printing
    #define HARDWARE_ID "REV421"
#elif (HARDWARE == REV4C)
    #define HARDWARE_ID "REV4C"
#else
    #define HARDWARE_ID "unknown"
#endif

#if (HARDWARE == REV421)
    #define LED_RED      // define pin addresses, blah blah...
#endif

/* ... */

printf("HARDWARE_ID %s\n", HARDWARE_ID);
```

This is ugly because it requires two separate symbols, `HARDWARE` (an integer, for comparison) and `HARDWARE_ID` (a string, for printing). And logic to generate the value of `HARDWARE_ID`.

Is there a better way?

---

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate of [how to compare string in C conditional preprocessor-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-string-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives).

That question (and answer) doesn't address how to get a printable string without ending up with two similar symbols.

(I did look at that answer before posting this question.)

Comment: Your second suggestion isn't so bad. Of course, you should not repeat the `#if` blocks for each thing you define, but define everything together. This approach also lets you control the valid values and allows you to issue an `#error` in the `#else` clause when no hardware was specified. (In `#if`s, unknown macros have a value of zero.)

Comment: @JosephQuinsey That question doesn't address how to get a printable string.

Comment: To get a printable string, see Jens Gustedt's answer [Way to compare strings in C preprocessor? (GCC)](//stackoverflow.com/a/34364515).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way of doing it is just to define the required configuration symbol, and then conditionally to define all of the others:

```
// Select config here
#define REV4C
//#define REV421

#ifdef REV4C
    #define HARDWARE_ID "REV4C"
    #define LED_RED
#elif defined(REV421)
    #define HARDWARE_ID "REV421"
    // .....
#else
//.......
#endif
```

Comment: Not all my #ifdefs are in one place like that, so that solution degenerates to my original "ugly but works" solution.

Comment: @nerdfever.com reorganize your code so they are in one place

Comment: @M.M Easy for you to say. The code is *already* organized so that certain other things are together in one place...

Answer (score 2):

To do the actual case analysis look at the comment that marks this as duplicate. To actually also have the value as a string you can use stringification, something like

```
#define STRINGIFY(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define HARDWARE_STR STRINGIFY(HARDWARE)
```

Answer (score 2):

A completely different approach would be to move the string-dependent logic to the *build*.

The C pre-processor is quite limited, but `make` (along with shell commands in rules) is the perfectly flexible string processor. E.g. with GNU `make`:

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG),REV4C)
    HARDWARE_ID = \"REV4C\"
else
    HARDWARE_ID = \"DEFAULT\"
endif
CFLAGS += -DHARDWARE_ID=$(HARDWARE_ID)
```

and call as

```
gmake CONFIG=REV4C
```