# Determine target name during compilation

Tags: ios, xcode

I have several targets and depending on them I need to import headers. I can do this by defining some preprocessor value and then check it with #ifdef, but I'm wondering, if there any way to do something like:

```
#if TARGET_NAME = "FirstTarget"
#import "SomeHeader.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use like below for example,

```
//Your current target's are defined
#define FIRST_TARGET   "FirstTarget"
#define SECOND_TARGET  "SecondTarget"
#define THIRD_TARGET   "ThirdTarget"  

//set which target u want to run
#define TARGET_NAME   FIRST_TARGET //SECOND_TARGET //THIRD_TARGET

//use like below

#if (TARGET_NAME == FIRST_TARGET) //or u can directly specify name instead of defining at the beginning
   #import "SomeHeader.h"
   //other headers
#elif (TARGET_NAME == SECOND_TARGET)
   //header to be in second target
#elif (TARGET_NAME == THIRD_TARGET)
   // other header
#endif
```

**Edit:**

i got it, it gives error because macros doesn't compare variable length values, for more details see this [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-string-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives) .

so in order to work u can change it like below,

```
//Your current target's are defined, instead of strings give some constant values
#define FIRST_TARGET   1//@"FirstTarget"
#define SECOND_TARGET  2//@"SecondTarget"
#define THIRD_TARGET   3//@"ThirdTarget"

//set which target u want to run 
#define TARGET_NAME   FIRST_TARGET //SECOND_TARGET //THIRD_TARGET

//use like below
#if TARGET_NAME == FIRST_TARGET
#import "SomeHeader.h"
//other headers
#elif (TARGET_NAME == SECOND_TARGET)
//header to be in second target
#elif (TARGET_NAME == THIRD_TARGET)
// other header

#endif
```

Comment: i will edit the answer .. sorry i didnt test it at the time of posting the answer

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't look much better, comparing to defining preprocessor macros. after some researching I've stopped at that solution