# How to use if else in macro(define)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I should separate Live and Dev URL.
So, I write this code

```
#define _APP_MODE @"real"

#if APP_MODE == dev
#define _BASE_URL @"http://devmall.aaa.com/m/app/"
#define _URL_FROM_SAFARI @"http://devmall.safari.com"
#else
#define _BASE_URL @"http://m.aaa.com/m/app/"
#define _URL_FROM_SAFARI @"http://m.safari.com"
```

but it always return dev_url

What is the best way to make sure that the URL is separated by APP_MODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strings dont work in objC preprocessor AFAIK

... see also [how to compare string in C conditional preprocessor-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-string-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives)

---

what I'd do (and is common) is using integers

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define DEV 0
#define REAL 1

#define APP_MODE REAL

#if APP_MODE == DEV
#define BASE_URL @"http://devmall.aaa.com/m/app/"
#define URL_FROM_SAFARI @"http://devmall.safari.com"
#else
#define BASE_URL @"http://m.aaa.com/m/app/"
#define URL_FROM_SAFARI @"http://m.safari.com"
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(BASE_URL);
    }
}
```

note: loose all the weird underscores :)) [if you can]

Comment: you cant - it is a compiler check