# C preprocessor confusing behaviour

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have shrunk my code `Aplicacion.c` to this minimum expression:

```
#if MIVAR == pirulo
#include "a_file.h"
#elif MIVAR == pepe
#include "b_file.h"
#endif
```

If I compile using `gcc -DMIVAR=pepe Aplicacion.c`, I would suppose it tries to include `b_file.h`, but I get the following error:

```
Aplicacion.c:4:10: fatal error: a_file.h: No such file or directory
#include "a_file.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Even if I define inside the source:

```
#define MIVAR pepe

#if MIVAR == pirulo
#include "a_file.h"
#elif MIVAR == pepe
#include "b_file.h"
#endif
```

When I execute `gcc Aplicacion.c` (or `gcc -E Aplicacion.c`), I still get the same error.

I feel it should be obvious, but I can not find out what is happening.

Any idea?

(All of this happens in Ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare strings in C conditional preprocessor-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-strings-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives)

Comment: In short, the test expression in `#if` can only involve integers and macros that expand to integers.  It can't compare strings or text.  You could define `pepe` and `pirulo` to some integer values, and that would work.

Comment: here is the relevant documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/conditional

Answer (score 3):

C preprocessor regards any undefined identifier as 0. So this one

```
#if MIVAR == pirulo
```

looks like `#if 0 == 0` for the preprocessor. Even if you define it

```
#define MIVAR pepe
```

still, it tries to compare `pepe` with `pirulo`, both are undefined, so it regards them as 0.

---

To fix this, you can define and compare your variables to numbers.

```
#define pirulo 5
#define pepe 9
#define MIVAR pepe
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, this answer also Nate's helped me to understand