# Proper usage of #if directive in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

The following structure for C preprocessor directive `#if` works well.

```
#define C  1

#if C==1
...
#endif
```

But I'd like to use something like this:

```
#define REAL double

#if REAL==double
...
#elif REAL==float
...
#else
   assert(0);
#endif
```

It's not valid. Is there a solution?

Comment: This answer may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-strings-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives

Comment: `Is there a solution?` Solution to? This seems for me to be XY question - you are using `#if` to choose some type related code - what is the real problem you are trying to solve? Why not just write `REAL a = 1` and forget about it?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I wanted to declare real variables in the code like this: `REAL r1, r2;` I found another way.

Comment: `REAL r1, r2;` so just do it, it should work with the code you've shown.. Anyway, why not `typedef`? `typedef double REAL` would be as good. `I found another way.` then should this question be closed?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I wanted `roundf()` be used instead of `round()` and so on when `REAL` was defined as `float`, and vice versa. First, I was going to use `#if`. Now I find `#ifdef` a better option. Anyway I hope that other people can learn from answer(s) to this question.

Comment: No need - just include [`tgmath.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/tgmath) in this case. And still would be cleaner to create a common abstraction/interface to the `REAL` type and use a single code flow, instead of multiple code flows.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I wasn't familiar with that. Thanks. :)

Comment: If you want to use different code depending on the type of something, that's what the `_Generic` keyword was created for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a solution?

There is a whole world of ways you can combine macro expansion with conditional compilation.  It's unclear which of them you would consider a solution, but here's a possibility:

```
#define doubledouble 1
#define floatfloat 1

#define concat_literal(x,y) x ## y
#define realtype(t1,t2) concat_literal(t1,t2)

// ...

#define REAL float

#if realtype(REAL, double)
    // REAL is double
#elif realtype(REAL, float)
    // REAL is float
#else
    // REAL is something else
#endif
```

The `realtype` macro works by macro-expanding its arguments and concatenating them together.  On rescan, if the result is `doubledouble` or `floatfloat` then that is expanded further to 1.  If it is an identifier that is not defined as a macro name, then the `#if` treats it as 0.

It's not foolproof, of course.  It does not work if `REAL` has a multi-token expansion, such as `long double`.  There's also a minor risk of collision with other defined macro names.