# How to compare string when precompile

Tags: c++, precompiler

```
#include <iostream>

#define MY_MACRO "hello"

int main() {
    #if MY_MACRO == "asdasd"
        std::cout << "The macro is not equal to hello" << std::endl;
    #else
        std::cout << "The macro is equal to hello" << std::endl;
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

In this form it would not compile successfully.

```
#include <iostream>

#define MY_MACRO hello

int main() {
    #if MY_MACRO == asdasd
        std::cout << "The macro is not equal to hello" << std::endl;
    #else
        std::cout << "The macro is equal to hello" << std::endl;
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

And in this form `#if MY_MACRO == XXX` would always judge as true.

So how to compare strings when pre-complie?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335888/how-to-compare-strings-in-c-conditional-preprocessor-directives , probably the answer applies to your use case.

Comment: You can't, but instead of macros (which you should almost never use) you can use `if constexpr`. You can compare strings at compile time with that.

Comment: @john And that means writing template functions because `if constexpr` only evaluates at compile time within templates.

Comment: For me question suffers from [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Why do you need compare strings in preprocessor phase? What problem this should solve? Depending on that it may turn out that `if conxtexpr` is good solution or it may turn out that completely different solution should be used which do not compare strings. A

Comment: @PepijnKramer: not necessary template, as long as both branches are valid.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Use numbers instead of strings, and give them names using macros:

   ```
   #define HELLO 1
   #define ASDASD 2

   #define MY_MACRO HELLO

   #if MY_MACRO == HELLO
   // ...
   #endif
   ```
2. Don't use preprocessor, use a plain `if` (or `if constexpr`, the only difference here is that the latter forces the condition to be a compile-time constant). This means that all branches have to be valid (have to compile) regardless of which one is choosen:

   ```
   #define MY_MACRO "hello"

   int main()
   {
       if constexpr (MY_MACRO == std::string_view("hello"))
       {

       }
   }
   ```

   Or make `MY_MACRO` a global `constexpr std::string_view` variable if you don't need to override it with compiler flags.